# MoneroPool help

Tags: mining-pools, mining-pool-setup

I'm new to mining and would like some help with moneropool.

Can someone tell me if the server is down.  It is stating that my hash rate is 7.8 but there is no update on pending hash rate.  It was working at first, but has stopped at 0.2 XMR.

Should I leave the pool and join another pool?

Thanks (using ethOS BTW)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not mining monerpool.com right now but it looks like the server is  working. Last block found was just a few minutes ago and payments are being given. How much exactly is your hash rate 7.8 h/s or 7.8 KH/s? If it is h/s it is very low and you may not get anything. How long it has stopped at 0.2 XMR and how long did you get to 0.2XMR? On the other hand if your having KH/s you should change pools since your losing a lot.

If you think the problem is on their side it is best is to contact moneropool.com directly https://moneropool.com/#support. It maybe a bug and you may get your actual XMR.

> support@moneropool.com